# Can a Breadth first search and depth first search have the same traversal on a specific graph ?

Tags: algorithm, graph

Can a Breadth first search and depth first search have the same traversal on a specific graph ? I tried with many graphs but didnt succeed

Comment: For example on a linked list, starting at its origin.

Answer (score 10):

Picture a tree in which only the rightmost child of any node has children. A binary tree, for example:

```
      o
    /   \
   o     o
       /   \
      o     o
          /   \
         o     o
```

Provided that your DFS always traverses the left node first, then your BFS and DFS will be the same.

You can extend this logic to any type of tree. If every node has at most one child that also has children, then your DFS and BFS will be the same if in the DFS you always traverse the nodes without children first.

Answer (score 2):

A breadth-first search will have the same traversal as a depth-first search provided that the graph has a maximum depth of 1, or a maximum breadth of 1.

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Well a Graph in a linked list (Ie a tree with each node, having exactly one child) format both traversals would be the same.